# How to link Eclipse to Java EE 5 SDK?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am busy setting up an Eclipse (Mars) programming environment for Java EE 5 SDK. (For legacy reason can't use EE7).

In Eclipse/Windows/Preferences Java points to jdk1.6.0_26.

I successfully created an EJB Project with EJB module version=3.0, with JRE definition pointing to jdk1.6.0_26.

Next I create a Session Bean and there the trouble starts. In the resulting bean I have two compiler errors:

```
    import javax.ejb.Stateless; // not found

    @Stateless // cannot be resolved to a type
```

It is obvious that the j2ee libraries can't be found.

I do have a jee5 sdk installed.

**Question: how do I link Eclipse to this jee5 sdk, so that the compiler error disappears.**

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE - in the project level properties, Targeted Runtimes added a pointer to the J2EE installation, but that didn't make a difference.

UPDATE-2 - maybe the key is in defining the server:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjtargetserver.html

> The target server setting is the default mechanism for setting the class path for J2EE projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need javaee.jar, which is to be included in the classpath if you work on a java project.

To get the jar:

- For Java EE 5: [enter link description here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javaee/javaee-api/5/javaee-api-5.jar).
- For Java EE 6:[enter link description here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar)

If you work on a maven project you have to add to the pom.xml of your project :

- For Java EE5:

  `<dependency>
     <groupId>javaee</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>5</version>
  </dependency>`
- For Java EE6:

  `<dependency>
     <groupId>javax</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed solve the compilation error. I added that jar to the project build path, but I would think that there must be a cleaner way to link the entire jee5 sdk to the project, instead of adding individual jars to the build path. I suspect this can be done via the server.